# Problems displaying buttons using null layout

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to display a window with an image background and buttons at the bottom of the window. I chose to use null layout so that I could position the buttons exactly how I want them - I didn't find any other layout that worked as nice, but when I run the method meant to display the window, it looks like [this](https://ibb.co/fsE4Gn).

```
public static void inGame() {

    BackgroundImg panel = new BackgroundImg    (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Simulator\\gamebg.png"));
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JButton sButton = new JButton("save");
    sButton.setBounds(0, 811, 80, 35);
    sButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    sButton.setFocusable(false);
    sButton.setFont(h3);
    JButton lButton = new JButton("load");
    sButton.setBounds(50, 809, 80, 35);
    lButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    lButton.setFocusable(false);
    lButton.setFont(h3);
    JButton mButton = new JButton("menu");
    sButton.setBounds(150, 809, 80, 35);
    mButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    mButton.setFocusable(false);
    mButton.setFont(h3);
    JButton qButton = new JButton("quit");
    sButton.setBounds(200, 809, 80, 35);
    qButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    qButton.setFocusable(false);
    qButton.setFont(h3);

    panel.add(sButton);
    panel.add(lButton);
    panel.add(mButton);
    panel.add(qButton);

    jfrm.getContentPane().add(panel);

    def();

    jfrm.setVisible(true);
}
```

here is the BackgroundImg class (I've used it before and it works fine)

```
public class BackgroundImg extends JPanel{
private Image img;

public BackgroundImg(String img) {
    this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
}

public BackgroundImg(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setSize(size);
    setLayout(null);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
}
```

and here is the def method that creates the basic window frame

```
public static void def() {
    jfrm.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
    jfrm.setSize(1400, 900);
    jfrm.setResizable(false);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also reproduce your problem.

Comment: Images should be posted in the forum not on an external website.

Answer (score 0):

> I chose to use null layout so that I could position the buttons exactly how I want them

Based on your code you are just attempting to position the buttons in a single row. There is no reason to use a null  layout.

Use the appropriate layout to position the buttons. This is easily done with a `FlowLayout`.

The basic code would be:

```
JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
buttonsPanel.setOpaque( false );
buttonsPanel.add(saveButton);
buttonsPanel.add(loadButton);
...

BackgroundImg background = new BackgroundImg(...);
background.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
background.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

frame.add( background );
```